# Same JNI Method in Two Different Java Files

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

Is it possible to use same JNI Method in Two Different Java Files ?

For Example, 
I have a method add() in c. i have written addJNI() in JNI File. now it possible to call addJNI() in two different file a.java and b.java

Hope that i am clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  You just need to load its native library in one java class file. and Use that class in as much files you want.

see

This is Hellojni.c

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include  "stdio.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return;
}
```

Now you can make any java class calling that jni method

```
class HelloWorld {

    public static native void print();  //native method

    static   //static initializer code
    {
        System.loadLibrary("CLibHelloWorld");
    } 

}
```

Now use that java class in Multiple java file as you want

```
    HelloWorld.print();
```

Comment: @Axit, is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Just wondering, how come this answer does not have an upvote :S

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it's the same as calling any other method. But just writing a method called addJNI() isn't going to work. You have to obey the header syntax generated by the javah tool.

Comment: can you give me more details what do you mean by header syntax

Comment: I mean what is generated by the `javah` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no question asking, Write a Class that contains Wrapper methods of JNI, which is like an interface class b\w Java and C.

Eg:

```
public class myWrapperClass
{
 static
{
  java.lang.System.loadLibraray("mylibraray");
}

public static void myfunctionOne(String str1, String str2);
public static int  myfunctionTwo(int num1, String str2);
----
---more methods
------

}

//To call these methods in different classes as they are abstract and static:

myWrapperClass.myfunctionOne("Hello", "JNI");

myWrapperClass.myfunctionTwo("1 , Number");
```

Hope this Helps.